# Making a rigged mesh interact with rigid bodies

Tags: animation, rigging, physics

I have sculpted a cat and rigged and made a small animation its all ok,
now i want my cat to play with objects like little toys, spheres or default cube,
I want to key its little paw around and hit other objects with it and i want to do this with physics simulation so its realistic.
I couldn't find anyway to do it, i tried a few things i saw here and there but cant make it work, im a newbie help pls

[image: said cat and cube]

Comment: you could give your cube a Rigid Body property, then keyframe the Animated option, so that it's manually animated at the beginning, then it bets animated by the physics

Comment: If you find applying physics to your model causes conflicts, you could leave the model as (animated) scenery only, (i.e. with no physics) and place small rigid body INVISIBLE planes or thin cubes at the paws.  Parent these to the respective limbs or bones.  These will react with other rigid bodies without interfering with the model itself.